# распарсить массив в скрипте

Tags: javascript, jquery

как вывести значение success
в скрипте

```
function add_to_cart(to_send, to_data){
        $.post("assets/get.php", { act:"addtocart", arr:to_send, arrd:to_data})
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data == "error"){

            }else{
             //  window.location = "/cart"; 
             alert(data);
            }

        });
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `data["success"]`

Comment: не работает тоже

Comment: `.done(function(data) { console.log(data);` - ?

Answer (score 3):

```js
function add_to_cart(to_send, to_data){
  $.post("assets/get.php", { 
    act: "addtocart", 
    arr: to_send, 
    arrd: to_data
  }).done(function(res) {
    if (res.success == 1) { // если успех работаем с данными
      console.log(res.message.total_count);
      console.log(res.message.total_cost);
      console.log(res.message.total_weight);
      
      console.log(res.data);
    } else { // если не удалось получить данные оповещаем и выводим ошибку
      alert('Упс, что-то пошло не так!');
      console.log(res);
    }
  }).fail(function(res) { // если произошла ошибка в запросе, также оповещаем и выводим ошибку в консоль
    alert('Ошибка получения данных.');
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: не работает res.success == 1

Comment: @Aslero Возможно 1 является строкой, а не числом, попробуйте `res.success == "1"`

Comment: @Aslero как написал в другом ответе Вячеслав, вы должны формировать массив в php и возвращаться его в формате JSON - `echo json_encode($array)`, лишь после этого вы сможете работать с данным так, как я описал в примере

Answer (score 2):

У вас сервер отдал По-моему не валилный ответ, для js это просто строка, я так понимаю на сервере просто был сделан var_dump или print_r, верните с сервера json с помощью функции json_encode и в js скрипте работайте с json, к полям в json можно обращаться через точку, например user.firstName